# Air XmlHttpRequest time out if remote server is offline?

Tags: javascript, air, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing an AIR application that communicates with a server via XmlHttpRequest.

The problem that I'm having is that if the server is unreachable, my asynchronous XmlHttpRequest never seems to fail. My onreadystatechange handler detects the OPENED state, but nothing else.

Is there a way to make the XmlHttpRequest time out?

Do I have to do something silly like using setTimeout() to wait a while then abort() if the connection isn't established?

**Edit:** 
Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377231/problem-xmlhttprequest-handle-server-connection-lost), but in my testing, wrapping my xmlhttprequest.send() in a try/catch block or setting a value on xmlhttprequest.timeout (or TimeOut or timeOut) doesn't have any affect.

Answer (score 2):

With AIR, as with XHR elsewhere, you have to set a timer in JavaScript to detect connection timeouts.

```
var xhReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("get", "infiniteLoop.phtml", true); // Server stuck in a loop.

var requestTimer = setTimeout(function() {
   xhReq.abort();
   // Handle timeout situation, e.g. Retry or inform user.
}, MAXIMUM_WAITING_TIME);

xhReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhReq.readyState != 4)  { return; }
  clearTimeout(requestTimer);
  if (xhReq.status != 200)  {
    // Handle error, e.g. Display error message on page
    return;
  }
  var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;  
};
```

[Source](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#Detecting_Errors)

Comment: In my air app the .status always returns 0, the air code examples do not seem to check status.

Comment: The satus 0 and readystate 4 was caused by IE being offline (work offline was set). Set it to work online and all was "fine"

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest timeout and ontimeout is a-syncronic and should be implemented in js client with **callbacks** :

Example:

```
function isUrlAvailable(callback, error) {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            return callback();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                return error();
            }, 8000);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open('GET', siteAddress, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```